# How to make this eth honeypot?

Tags: security

I am sure everyone must have seen this honeypot 0xb7605ddc0327406a7ac225b9de87865e22ac5927
Where the eth is automatically send to another parent address..
How can i make the same thing? For educational purposes obviously.

Comment: There is no smart contract at the address you provided.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this thread
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2237480.0
it will explain it .

in short its not a contract. its normal wallet address but the real owner of it is using a bot he created and link it to the wallet to transfer the funds to other set of wallets .

for example they are :
0xb7377609c00Ef9b7eb428E3F338d9604e2A84850
0x4DAbfEEbDEbf38267a5ccc1886F51A4b730287E8